# How can I create a Yahoo Pipe to convert Json into RSS

Tags: json, rss

I'd like to convert JSON to RSS and Yahoo Pipes is the best web service I can think of for this purpose.  I even found a pipe that unfortunately didn't work and only returned a null result.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=Qvdm_tq_3RGbo7Wt1JzWFw

The URL I was trying to pass through it (as a test) is this one:

http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json

Ideally passing it through the pipe would return this format:

http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss

Comment: Isn't it a deprecated service?  http://pipes.yqlblog.net/2012/12/10/pipes-translate-module/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect, but here's a start:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=e5ad36b6c4651a5b533ef39f5009c6a5

The JSON of each item looks like this, for example:

```
{
    "a": "sentur332", 
    "d": "http://www.8445restore.com Every year, millions of properties all over the world suffer from the threat and destruction related to water damage to the house. Get a pro to do your water restoration project. http://feliked816.livejournal.com/1350.html", 
    "n": "", 
    "u": "http://icio.us/+ac2772f88bd79", 
    "t": [
        ""
    ], 
    "dt": "2014-12-23T05:17:55Z"
}
```

To convert it to RSS using Yahoo! Pipes:

- Use **Fetch Data** component to fetch the JSON content:

  - URL: http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json
  - Path: json
- Use **Create RSS** to map the JSON values to RSS fields

  - Title comes from `d` in the JSON, so use `item.d`
  - Author comes from `a` in the JSON, so use `item.a`
  - Publishing date comes from `dt` in the JSON, so use `item.dt`
  - Link comes from `u` in the JSON, so use `item.u`